# Flip Page animation in UWP

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, page-flipping

I am developing a UWP app for file reader in C#, and I use two UserControl include `Image` to render the file page bitmaps. Now when user horizontally swipe the either screen, I'd like the file will flip to previous or next two pages, I just update the page buffer directly now, but I want the **animation of the flipping page process**, the animation effect is simulating turning a real book, can anyone help? So when user swipe on right screen from right to left, page 1 and 2 will turn to page 3 and 4.

[image]

Comment: What kind of animation to be precise? What is the desired effect?

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: Can anyone help? I think it does matter about page Transitions